# Zero-width space for Persian typing in lyx

Tags: spacing, lyx, xepersian, persian

I want to use Lyx to write in Persian. In Persian we have a space character named "zero-width space" or "half-space" and in a standard keyboard, we type it with "Shift-Space" shortcut. It is "U-200C" in utf-8 encoding.

(More about zero-width space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)

In Lyx I cannot type that, when pressing "Shift-Space" nothing happens. I tried to specify a new shortcut to mimic that, but Lyx cannot recognize such combination in Persian keyboard. Also, I changed some definitions in .kmap but it didn't work.

I think the problem is that when I hold shift-key, Lyx remap the keyboard and "Shift-Space" has no mean then. Also when I copy-paste some Persian text that include zero-width space, Lyx replaces all of them with simple space.
In other latex editors there is no problem, not in typing and not in compiling.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to report this to the devs as a bug. Unfortunately, this isn’t really a question or on-topic here. This isn’t really something that TeX coding can help you with.

Comment: You might be able to type the character with the left-alt key on Windows or the Compose key on Linux, but neither is a great workaround.

Comment: If you wanted to make it very explicit in your source that you are using this character, you could define it as `^^^^200c`, but that also isn’t what you were asking.

Comment: @MdRaHP Are you using the Persian kmap file in LyX?

Comment: A LyX bug report was opened here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545399/zero-width-space-for-persian-typing-in-lyx

Answer (score 0):

Using LyX 2.3.3 with Linux with UTF-8 system locales and typing the UTF-8 character `U+200B` will produce this in the hidden LaTeX preamble (visible only in the Code Preview Pane):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.

\newcommand*\LyXZeroWidthSpace{\hspace{0pt}}
```

And the character is changed by the  `\LyXZeroWidthSpace` macro in the body of the document, showing nothing in the main edit window.

How to type `U+200B` is your keyboard is another question, because is OS-dependent, program-dependent and probably keyboard-language dependent.

In my Linux with Spanish keyboard and UTF-8 system locales, is type:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

I cannot test in Windows, but Google say that, making sure that <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> **is turned on**, you can type this using the **numeric keypad**:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+{<kbd>8</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>} 
or maybe

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+{<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>}<kbd>B</kbd>

That is, maintaining <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed while typing all the numbers with the number keys of the right, but **not** those usually under the <kbd>Fx</kbd> keys.

If none of this work, there must be another specific method for your OS/keyboard to type special uft-8 characters that have not dedicated keys in your keyboard.

The case of U+200C ('ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER', not "ZERO WIDTH SPACE") is similar, but simpler, since it is substituted  by `\textcompwordmark` that is already defined (therefore, nothing is added to the preamble). In Superuser there a question of [how type u+200C](https://superuser.com/questions/1410431/how-to-type-directly-with-keyboard-the-u200c-character) that include an answer specific for Persian or Arabic keyboards.